# WebSocket Flash Application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome

There is a flash application (app.swf)

I am trying to figure out how the communication is done, I tried using Chrome Inspector to check requests but I was not able to detect anything.

Using wireshark I detect connection to a remote ip and port 443 but it is not shown in Chrome.

Do Flash application not use Chrome for sending this communication ?
How to detect the traffic sent and received ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Port 443 is usually assigned to HTTPS, i.e., HTTP over TLS/SSL (encrypted).

Depending on the nature of the Flash application you want to listen to, chances are there's some other process in Chrome making those calls (it's fairly unusual for your average Flash application to need secure socket connections).

However, if this connection is indeed coming from the Flash application, I'm afraid you're out of luck in trying to decrypt the intercepted packets.

Normal HTTP GET and POST requests will show up in the Network panel in Chrome's Inspector. Unencrypted TCP socket packets should show up in Wireshark.

Comment: Is there any way that I can do it ? For example hooking the function ? Or injecting the AS3 function ? Or any other approach ?

Comment: @circler If the Flash application is communicating over secure sockets, I can't think of a legitimate reason for you to intercept those messages.

Comment: well i get you what u mean, i am tampering with things i shouldn't be tampering with, or accessing things i shouldn't access. But honestly it's a self challenging and curiosity to know thing. It's not even a specific app.

Comment: Well, since you're in control of the client end, you can _in theory_ read the messages. SSL/TLS provides security on the _transport layer_, which is making it hard to intercept and/or modify messages _between you and the receiver_. In practice you'll find it challenging though, and I believe it's a discussion more fitting in a security forum.